# skip the specific text inside the <td> tag , python beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

this is my html file

```
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td style="font-weight: bold;"><a href="#" onclick="javascript:TollPlazaPopup(272);"> Kherki Daula </a></td> 
<td style="font-weight: bold;">60 <a onclick="return popitup(" https:="" www.google.co.in="" maps="" @28.395604,76.98176,17.52z="" data="!5m1!1e1?hl=en')'" href="https://www.google.co.in/maps/@28.395604,76.98176,17.52z/data=!3m1!1e3!5m1!1e1?hl=en" target="_Blank"> (Live Traffic)</a> &nbsp;&nbsp; - &nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="#" title="Click here to get estimated travel time." id="0-232X" onclick="javascript:TollPlazaTrafficTime(272,this);">ET</a>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2</td>
<td style="font-weight: bold;"><a href="#" onclick="javascript:TollPlazaPopup(213);"> Shahjahanpur </a></td>
<td style="font-weight: bold;">125 <a onclick="return popitup(" https:="" www.google.co.in="" maps="" @27.99978,76.430522,17.52z="" data="!5m1!1e1?hl=en')'" href="https://www.google.co.in/maps/@27.99978,76.430522,17.52z/data=!3m1!1e3!5m1!1e1?hl=en" target="_Blank"> (Live Traffic)</a> &nbsp;&nbsp; - &nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="#" title="Click here to get estimated travel time." id="1-179X" onclick="javascript:TollPlazaTrafficTime(213,this);">ET</a>
</td>
</tr>
```

Now I am scraping so result is coming like

```
Sr No.  Toll Plaza  Car/Jeep/Van(Rs.)
1   Kherki Daula    60 (Live Traffic)    -    ET
2   Shahjahanpur    125 (Live Traffic)    -    ET
                 Total Charges(Rs.) 90
```

I want to skip the text (Live Traffic - ET) from rows

my python code is

```
tbody = soup('table' ,{"class":"tollinfotbl"})[0].find_all('tr')[3:]
for row in tbody:
    cols = row.findChildren(recursive=False)
    cols = [ele.text.contents[0] for ele in cols]
    if cols:
        sno = str(cols[0])
        Toll_plaza = str(cols[1])
        cost = str(cols[2])

        query = "INSERT INTO tryroute (sno,Toll_plaza, cost) VALUES (%s, %s, %s);"
```

when I am using `.contents[0]`  I am getting an error `cols = [ele.text.content[0] for ele in cols]
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'content'`

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `re` to extract the data from the raw. You don't need to get `content[]` since that is prone to errors coz you're explicitly giving the index and not flexible.

Add `import re` at the top before copying the code below.

```
for row in tbody:
    cols = row.findChildren(recursive=False)
    cols = [ele.text for ele in cols]
    if cols:
        sno = str(cols[0])
        Toll_plaza = str(cols[1])
        cost_raw = str(cols[2])

        compiled = re.compile('^(\d+)\s*\(', flags=re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL)
        match = re.search(compiled, cost_raw)
        if match:
            cost = match.group(1)

        query = "INSERT INTO tryroute (sno,Toll_plaza, cost) VALUES (%s, %s, %s);"
```

Let me know if you need clarification.

Comment: No, its not printing those row which contains text `'Live Traffic'` . It just printing the last row ,
`| Total Charges(Rs.) | 90`

Comment: I thought you want to skip Live traffic?

Comment: I want to skip the text only `(Live Traffic)    -    ET`
and if possible then last row of table.

Comment: So you just want the number 60 and 125?

Comment: `1   Kherki Daula    60`
`2   Shahjahanpur    125`

yes like this only

Comment: Thanks a lot.. it's working 
can u plz clear me this
`compiled = re.compile('^(\d+)\s*\(', flags=re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL)
        match = re.search(compiled, cost_raw)
        if match:
            cost = match.group(1)`

Comment: That is a regular expression, it means you are extracting all numbers (\d+) before the parethesis "\(" and clearing all excess space. Please mark this as answer if it solves your issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You are getting this error because you are trying to use "contents" on a str object i.e ele.text

```
ele.text # returns a string object (which in your case contains the whole text in that particular tag)
```

To get contents of the tag, you have to do like this

```
ele.contents # inside your list comprehension, this will return a list of all the children of that particular tag
```

Comment: When I am using only `ele.text` , getting an error
`tbody = soup('table' ,{"class":"tollinfotbl"})[0].find_all('tr')[3:]
IndexError: list index out of range`
because my table structure is 
`1 Joya 60 (Live Traffic)    -    ET
2 Dasna 30 (Live Traffic)    -    ET
                 Total Charges(Rs.) 90`

Comment: So is there any way that I can skip to print last row of table, as well as skip that text inside the table

Comment: In your case, you can use ele.contents[0] this will return 60 . Since, ele.contents returns the list of ele's children and it will look like ['60', <a></a>, and other children if any]

Comment: this is throwing an error `tbody = soup('table' ,{"class":"tollinfotbl"})[0].find_all('tr')[3:]
IndexError: list index out of range` because my table last row structure is diffrent , if i can delete the last row from table only then i can use `ele.contents[0]`

Comment: plz check once my table structure.

Comment: Please add the last row in the above table structure.

Comment: And you can write your list comprehension like this [ele.contents[0].text for ele in cols if isinstance(ele.contents[0], Tag) else ele.contents[0]] Do import Tag with BeautifulSoup i.e from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Tag.

Comment: `1   Kherki Daula    60 (Live Traffic)    -    ET`
`2   Shahjahanpur    125 (Live Traffic)    -    ET`
                 `Total Charges(Rs.) 90`
this is my table, last row don't have any value in 1st column.(I want to skip this row also)

Comment: Slice your last row from tbody as tbody[:-1]